# How to uninstall an exe file using wix

Tags: wix

I am able to install/run an exe using the below wix code snippet which creates some registry entries as well

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="D:\RegUtil.exe" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchRegExe" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action='LaunchRegExe' After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I am able to uninstall the exe using the value "D:\RegUtil.exe /uninstall" in normal command prompt. 
Is there a way to accomplish the uninstalling of RegUtil.exe using the value "D:\RegUtil.exe /uninstall" in wix

Answer (score 0):

You can run a Quiet Execution Custom Action to uninstall it, as below:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html

Example:-

```
   <!--Sets command-->
   <CustomAction Id="SetQtExecCmdLine_UninstallRegUtil"
                 Execute="immediate"
                 Property="QtExecCmdLine"
                 Return="check"
                 Value="D:\RegUtil.exe /uninstall" />

   <!--Runs command-->
   <CustomAction Id="QtExec_UninstallRegUtil"
                 BinaryKey="WixCA"
                 DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
                 Execute="immediate"
                 Return="check" />

  <!--InstallExecuteSequence-->
  <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="SetQtExecCmdLine_UninstallRegUtil" After="CostFinalize"/>
    <Custom Action="QtExec_UninstallRegUtil" After="SetQtExecCmdLine_UninstallRegUtil"/>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: How to make it as a relative path Value="D:\RegUtil.exe /uninstall" here?